# What is this woodcut / engraving like / illustrative design style called? (as seen on the US dollar sign)

Tags: illustration, style-identification, borders

Where can I find books / references / inspirations to learn the principles behind these graphic patterns?

It's often seen in luxury or heritage style products, as well as the us dollar sign. What is the art or graphic design style called? I understand that this may be a mix of various styles, but is there an overlapping or overall name for this art style?

Specific examples include Simon Frouw's work as they all seem to fall under this category:

https://www.behance.net/simonfrouws

http://cargocollective.com/simonfrouws/Spier-Sparkling-Wine

More examples:

[image: Sentinels cards example]

[image: Chinese lattice mixed with this style for nike]

[image]

[image: wine design example]

[image: Card example]

Looking at them they just look elegant and old-school luxurious with all the intricate details that looks hand crafted. From looking at the various examples I gathered there seems to be elements or art deco geometric patterns, halftone engravings styles, monograms, and heritage crests

I'm probably the most interested in the beautiful decorative geometric & illustrative or graphic design patterns as seen in the background.

What's the principle behind these designs? What's it called and where can I learn to make them?

Comment: There's no one style here. You have a mix of hand illustration, engraving (or drawn to look like engraving), hand lettering, type swashes, embossing, etc. You could all lump it under 'hand illustration evocative of late 1800's commercial art' perhaps.

Comment: @DA01 Thanks! looking up late 19th century has definitely helped! There are certain decorative elements that i'd like to learn. specifically the stuff this guy does: http://www.howdesign.com/design-creativity/fonts-typography/victorian-typography/. any recommendations for resources on stuff like bifurcated serifs, filigree, etc?

Comment: that's pretty much all 'hand lettering'. Historically also a skillset of the sign painter. I'd google for historical books on the subject matter. AS for learning that stuff, I'd say it's 90% practice, practice, practice! :)

Answer (score 7):

As for the 'style' you see on printed US Currency, that is engraving. It's more of a technique than anything. [See the answer here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/4576/is-there-a-name-for-this-line-based-halftone-style/4580#4580).

That said, the samples show aren't all engraving. A few borrow (namely 'A' monogram) but you have other techniques and styles going on.

The first two are just decorative illustrations. They are evocative of a lot of late 1800's style advertising.

The 3rd we discussed, and is the closest to engraving.

The 4th is emulating hand lettering--specifically gold plated signage. Also something you say a lot of in the late 1800s into the 1900s. It was traditionally done in gold leaf and paint on glass. There's also decorative type swashes included.

The last is physically embossing (raised decoration) and stylistically perhaps best described as 'playing card style'.

I wouldn't call any of the styles shown as 'woodcut'. That's perhaps related, but tends to have a bit of a different aesthetic.

Answer (score 2):

The patterns you're talking about are [*guilloche*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guilloch%C3%A9) :

> Guilloché (or guilloche) is a decorative engraving technique in which
>   a very precise intricate repetitive pattern or design is mechanically
>   engraved into an underlying material. Specifically, it involves a
>   technique of engine turning, using a machine of the same name, also
>   called a rose engine lathe. This improved upon the more time-consuming
>   practice of making similar designs by hand and allowed for greater
>   delicacy, precision, and closeness of the line, as well as greater
>   speed.

*Historically*, in the *1911 Encyclopædia Britannica* article:

> GUILLOCHE, a French word for an ornament, either painted or carved,
>   which was one of the principal decorative bands employed by the Greeks
>   in their temples or on their vases. Guilloches are single, double or
>   triple; they consist of a series of circles equidistant one from the
>   other and enclosed in a band which winds round them and interlaces.
>   This guilloche is of Asiatic origin and was largely employed in the
>   decoration of the Assyrian palaces, where it was probably copied from
>   Chaldean work, as there is an early example at Erech, which dates from
>   the time of Gudea (2294 B.C.). The ornament as painted by the Greeks
>   has almost entirely disappeared, but traces are found in the temple of
>   Nemesis at Rhamnus; and on the terra-cotta slabs by which the timber
>   roofs of Greek temples were protected, it is painted in colours which
>   are almost as brilliant when first produced, those of the Treasury of
>   Gela at Olympia being of great beauty. These examples are double
>   guilloches, with two rows of circles. In the triple guilloche, the
>   centre row of circles comes half-way between the others, and the
>   enclosing band crosses diagonally both ways, lacing alternately. The
>   best example of the triple guilloche is that which is carved on the
>   torus moulding of the base and on the small convex moulding above the
>   echinus of the capitals of the columns of the Erechtheum at Athens. It
>   was largely employed in Roman work, and the single guilloche is found
>   almost universally as a border in mosaic pavements, not only in Italy
>   but throughout Europe. In the Renaissance in Italy it was also a
>   favourite enrichment for borders and occasionally in France and
>   England.

Comment: Some of the samples do use a guilloche as one of the elements in the design. That said, a guilloche is more of an element of design rather than an overall aesthetic style.

Answer (score -2):

I believe the style is Art Nouveau

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/115856)